# Xpath to get text following label

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I want to get items according to their (preceding) `<label>` attributes, like this:

```
 <div>
      <ul>
          <li class="phone">
               <label>Mobile</label>
               312-999-0000
 <div>
      <ul>
          <li class="phone">
               <label>Home</label>
               312-999-0001
```

I want to put the first number in the "Mobile" column/list, and the second in the Home list. I currently have code grabbing both of them, but I don't know the proper syntax for getting the label as it is in the source. This is what I'm using now:

```
for target in targets:
    item = CrawlerItem()
    item['phonenumbers'] = target.xpath('div/ul/li[@class="phone"]/text()').extract()
```

How should I rewrite that for item['mobilephone'] and item['homephone'], using the labels?

Comment: Just a comment, I highly recommend putting the phone number inside an an element versus hoping for text to appear after the fact.  Different browers can interpret the DOM differently and could screw up your code.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer while finishing up the question, and thought I should share it:

```
item['mobilephone'] = target.xpath('div/ul/li/label[contains (text(),"Mobile")]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
item['officephone']= target.xpath('div/ul/li/label[contains (text(),"Office")]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
```